# PHP: Get specific value from simplexml array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am pretty new to PHP an XML and hope you can help me with this. 
Searching the forum didn't help me yet to find an answer to my specific issue.

I have a PHP page with a simplexml array that looks like the following, just longer:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object 
    ( 
       [textID] => Array 
                ( 
                   [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                       ( 
                          [textID] => 1 
                          [content] => Text1 
                       ) 
                   [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                       ( 
                          [textID] => 2 
                          [content] => Text2
                       ) 
                   [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                       ( 
                          [textID] => 3 
                          [content] => Text3 
                       ) 
                )
      )
```

Now I am trying to echo out a specific value from this array by referring to its ID which is an integer. 
The only way I get this working is the following but this just goes by the order within the array, not by the actual ID:

```
    <?php echo $objTexts->textID[1]->content; ?>
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing here ?

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Can u show a piece of your xml?

Comment: I did, it's at the beginning of the code.

Comment: I copied my XMl 1:1 and just shortened it.

Comment: Hmm? it's looks strange) It must looks somthing like this:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<objTexts>
 <textID>
  <content>
  Some text
  </content>
 </textID>
</objTexts>

Comment: That's how it looks when I use print_r on the page. I am creating it through a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve here? Do you want to lookup the textID value directly without calling the array textID?

Comment: i have no idea, whats wrong. Try to see this exaples, mb it will be helpfull:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks, I checked this already. I think the issue is that I need to tell it somehow that the IDs are integers.

Comment: So i'm think something wrong with ur xml. I was trying this:
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<objTexts>
 <textID>
  <textID>1</textID>
  <content>Some text</content>
 </textID>
 <textID>
   <textID>2</textID>
   <content>Some text</content>
 </textID>
 <textID>
  <textID>3</textID>
  <content>Some text</content>
 </textID>
</objTexts>
XML;

$objTexts = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
print_r($objTexts);
echo '<br />';
echo $objTexts->textID[0]->content;
And it works fine :/

Comment: Here is an example: My code above has the number 1 in square brackets. This gives me the content from the second textID in my array. The actual textID value for this is 2 so I would like to call this by referring to its value 2 instead of to its position 1.

Comment: Update: I got it working with the following approach: This is probably not the best way of writing it but it's working. If someone has a suggestion on how I can improve or shorten this please let me know. <?php foreach ($objTexts->textID as $item) {if((string) $item->textID=="2") {echo (string) $item->content;} } ?> Thanks, Tim

Comment: There is no such thing as "a simplexml array" - a simplexml **object** is a wrapper around a low-level XML parser, and functions like `print_r` don't always represent everything that you can access with it; it's generally better to just show the XML itself.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML has no way of knowing that the `textID` identifies which node is which - it is just another element in the XML.

Based on your sample output, your XML is a little confusing as you have multiple elements called `textID` which each have a single child, also called `textID`, which has a different meaning. Nonetheless, what you want to do can be achieved either by looping through all the outer `textID` elements and testing the value of their inner `textID` element:

```
foreach ( $objTexts->textID as $item )
{
     if ( $item->textID == '2' )
     {
          ...
     }
}
```

Or, you could use XPath, which is a fairly simple query language for XML, and is supported within SimpleXML in the form of [the `->xpath()` method](https://www.php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath). In your case, you want to find a `textID` node which contains a `textID` child with a particular value, so the code would look something like this:

```
 // ->xpath always returns a plain PHP array - not a SimpleXML object
 $xpath_results = $objTexts->xpath('//textID[textID=2]');
 
 // If you're certain you only want the first result:
 echo $xpath_results[0]->content;
 
 // If you might want multiple matches
 foreach ( $xpath_results as $item )
 {
     ...
 }
```